# Dealing with multiple POST requests in Django views

Tags: python, django, post, view

I would like to know if it is possible to handle different POST requests in a Django view method. For example, take the following code:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST['value_one']:
            # Do stuff here

        elif request.POST['value_two']:
            # Do stuff here

        elif request.POST['value_three']:
            # Do stuff here

        else:
            # Do something else
```

Is it possible to do something like this within a Django view? If not, then what would be the best approach to handle such a situation?

Comment: Yes it is possible. This is a usual case when you have multiple buttons in a form.

Comment: Go ahead this is normal things done with if statement

Comment: I have tried it and I get a 'MultiValueDictKeyError' error.

Answer (score 1):

Technically this is not "Dealing with multiple post requests" (which is kind of a nonsense - a view will only handle one single request - whatever the method - at a time), but "handling different values from a post request" (or from a GET request FWIW, it doesn't change much).

Now to answer your question: yes of course it is possible - as you would find out if you tried by yourself -, and is a rather common pattern. You just may want to use `request.POST.get("whatever", default)` instead to avoid having to deal with `KeyError` when some key is not part of the request's body (POST) or querystring (GET).